# AWS Sagemaker MultiModel endpoint additional dependencies

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I am trying to deploy a [multi model endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-model-endpoints.html#how-multi-model-endpoints-work) on aws sagemaker. However some of my models have additional dependencies. I am following the [huggingface's documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/en/inference#user-defined-code-and-modules)
on creating user-defined-code and requirements.

My zipped artifacts have a `code` directory with `requirements.txt` and yet when I deploy the model and try invoking it with the python aws sdk. I get `ModuleNotFound` errors during my imports.

I know its finding my `inference.py` file since its failing to find those modules that I import.

It should be noted that these models I am deploying are trained and made outside of sagemaker and I am trying to bring them into sagemaker.

The container image I am using is
`'763104351884.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-inference:2.1.0-transformers4.37.0-cpu-py310-ubuntu22.04'`

Answer (score 0):

Hey [Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10466743/lucas)

It seems to me that you're confusing/mixing two different methods to deploy models in SageMaker.

If you want to create a [Multi-Model Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/create-multi-model-endpoint.html), unfortunately, you'll need to create a Docker Image that adheres to SageMaker's requirements (e.g. which ports to expose, etc.). You can read more on this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-multi-model-build-container.html).

The HuggingFace guide you've been following is designed for single-model endpoints, and does indeed enable you to use custom dependencies. You may wish to simply create single-model endpoints for all of your models, by following the below steps:

- Clone the model from Hugging Face using git
- Create a `code/` directory (within the model dir) and add an `inference.py` file
- Include two functions in the inference file, these **must** be called `model_fn()` and `predict_fn()`. The former is used only when the endpoint is initialised, and must return the model & tokeniser, the latter is called for each inference request. You can use the `predict_fn()` to include custom logic.
- Create a tarball (`model.tar.gz`) with all the model artefacts (incl. your custom inference code). It should be formatted as below.

```
model.tar.gz/
|- pytorch_model.bin
|- ....
|- code/
  |- inference.py
  |- requirements.txt
```

- Finally, upload the tarball to S3 and pass the S3 URI to SageMaker when creating a model/endpoint.

There's a great [notebook from Hugging Face](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb) covering this whole process. It's the best guide I've been able to find so far. If you copy it word-for-word, and only modify the `inference.py` script, you should be successful.

Here's an example of an `inference.py` I've used previously, as you can see, Hugging Face Pipelines work too!

```py
from transformers import pipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from DirectQuoteUtils import reformat
import torch
import os

def model_fn(model_dir):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)
    model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_dir)
    pipe = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    return pipe

def predict_fn(data, pipeline):
    pipe = pipeline
    outputs = []
    
    # FORMAT FOR MODEL INPUT:
    # {               # list of strings
    #     "inputs": ["Donald Trump is the president of the US", "Joe Biden is the United States president"]
    # }
    
    modelData = pipe(data['inputs'])
    
    for prediction in modelData:
        cleanPred = reformat(prediction)
        outputs.append(cleanPred)
        
    return {
        # "device": device, # handy to check if CUDA is being used
        "outputs": outputs
    }
```